# sorting is not working in footable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have integrated footable in my applcation. I have included footable.js, footable.filter.js, footable.paginate.js, footable.sort.js and the css files(footable.core.css and footable.metro.css). Pagination and filtering is working perfectly, But sorting is not working.

```
<table class='footable' data-page-navigation=".pagination" data-filter="#filter" data-page-size="10" data-page-previous-text="prev" data-page-next-text="next">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sort-initial="true" class='sort-column'>Name</th>
      <th class='sort-column'>Description</th>      
      <th>Actions</th>     
      <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @fee_categories.each do |fee_category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to fee_category.name, fee_category %></td>
        <td><%= fee_category.description %></td>
        <td>          
          <%= link_to edit_fee_category_path(fee_category) do %>
            <i class='icon-white icon-pencil btn-primary btn'></i>
          <% end  %>
          <%= link_to fee_category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
            <i class='icon-white icon-remove btn-danger btn'></i>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to "Add Particulars", "#" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

and the js file is

```
$('.footable').footable();
```

Comment: What is the order of yours scripts?

Comment: as well arrows are also not shown in table.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar problem. The way I solved it was by removing all the extra options until it started working.  By doing that I was able to find what was causing the problem.  In my case I had "data-sort='false'" where I didn't expect it.

Does this work for you:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="../css/footable.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../js/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/footable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/footable.sort.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-type="numeric" data-sort-initial="true">Number</th>
                <th>Leter</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('table').footable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I see that you're trying to use pagination too.  Maybe if you just focus on sorting and then add pagination, you might have better luck.

Comment: It is working. But sorting symbol is not appear, instead a circle is there. I have included both footable.core.css and footable.metro.css.

Comment: what happens if you remove footable.metro.css?  One issue I ran into was I was adding the class information to the header and that would cause odd results.  You don't need to add anything to a table.  In my example above I don't add any class information in the <th>, except for the Number column, this is because footable adds if for you.